# How to pass parameter to a constructor of fxml controller class in javafx?

Tags: javafx

How to pass parameter in the fxml controller class constructor?

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Online Poker");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 400));
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not directly pass parameter into the FXMLLoader Controller constructor, instead you get the controller from the FXMLLoader instance and calling a method on the controller to initialize it with parameter.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
ViewController viewController = loader.<ViewController>getController();
viewController.initParameter(parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I guess correctly from the start method, this is an instance of Application. Try the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.Parameters.html):

```
this.getParameters();
```

(this is assuming you want to access the application parameters as the term "constructor" suggests)